# WEVTUtil Filter from a source

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, command, wevtutil

I have been trying to filter the Application log from WEVTUtil in order to view specific log. However, in filtering for event id 1036, there are two separate publishers. 
I want to be able to just get the events from MsiInstaller, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to and I can't seem to find anything on this.

```
wevtutil qe Application "/q:*[System [(EventID=1036)]] /f:text
```

This is working for me, but it is not showing me the events from MsiInstaller alone. How should I go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question after enough head scratching! This filters out all the queries that have conflicting sources (ie. not the one I wanted).

```
wevtutil qe Application "/q:*[System [(EventID=1036)][Provider[@Name='MsiInstaller']]]" /f:text
```

Answer (score 1):

A PowerShell alternative is [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7).

Example:

```bsh
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID=1033;ProviderName='MsiInstaller'}
```

You can set the log name and Event ID as necessary.